# Why my css is not changing items in div tags

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css so I'm learning and practicing by making a sample website, but I've hit a problem where I can't seem to use div id tags to edit with css, the css is working perfectly fine editing anything not a div tag.  I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

This is the html code I'm working with:

```
<body>

    <div id="nav">
      <div id="container">
        <ul>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Getting Involved</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="centernav">
          <ul>
            <li>Website</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li>Showtimes</li>
          <li>Announcements</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="website-name">
        <h1>Website title</h1>
        <p>info</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

My css code:

```
div.nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 { 
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}  

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I think you should consider reading about CSS selectors. This is very basic question of CSS and good that you're learning but try reading W3Schools first before posting question.

Comment: For `id="nav"` use css selector for id `#nav` and for `class="nav"` use css selector for class `.nav`. - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had seen some html/css code examples a while back using id, while the course I'm going through at codecademy that uses class and I ended up using id in place of class.  I'm still going through the course (which has yet to go into detail the difference between class and id), however nothing sticks with me unless I use it in practical application so I just needed to practice with what I've learned so far.  My apologies that my question was so basic but thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been using the wrong selector, `div.nav` selects all `<div class="nav">`, instead, `div#nav` selects the `<div id="nav">`, but as id's are unique, you can just use `#nav` :)

See it working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eokxhLgw/) for portability, or here in this code snippet:

```css
#nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 { 
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}  

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="nav">
      <div id="container">
        <ul>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Getting Involved</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="centernav">
          <ul>
            <li>Website</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li>Showtimes</li>
          <li>Announcements</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="website-name">
        <h1>Website title</h1>
        <p>info</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Maybe this is useful, [**css selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user3638890 No problem, remember, if you found an answer that works for you, click the green tick next to it to mark the question as answered! See ya :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div#nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 { 
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}  

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank worked, thank!  Do you know why the # is working instead of the . ?

Comment: Your using ids instead of classes if you were using classes you could do div.nav.

Answer (score 1):

A `.` indicates a class and a `#` an id. Change `div.nav` to `div#nav`.